# Ref on svg <path /> doesn't have "getTotalLength()"-Method

Tags: reactjs, dom, svg

I want to create a component which renders an SVG path element like so:

```
class Path extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.refCallback = this.refCallback.bind(this);
  }

  refCallback(element) {
    console.log("Element: ", element, element.getTotalLength());
  }

  render() {
    const { data, id } = this.props

    return (
      <path d={ data } id={ id } ref={ this.refCallback } />
    );
  }
}
```

I expected to get the DOM Node of the path and then use the "getTotalLength()" method on it. But instead I get the following output in the console for the path element:

```
Element: <path d="M11.859375,0.88671875 C9.10229798,32.1448978 3.72401281,62.1847019 0.921875,92.3632812" id="Path"></path>
```

And for "element.getTotalLength()" this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: element.getTotalLength is not a function
```

I have no clue why it's behaving like this. I expected to get the DOM Element and use "getTotalLength()".

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Path without svg does support the getTotalLength() function.

It works

```
<svg>
   <path d={ data } id={ id } ref={ this.refCallback } />
 </svg>
```

Comment: Thank you, it was really that simple! Helped mit a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `svg` tag and you can first assign the ref of the component and then use the DOM methods.

You can try something like this

```
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.pathref.getTotalLength());
  }
  render() {
    const { data, id } = this.props
    return(
      <svg>
        <path ref={(ref) => { this.pathref = ref; }} d={ data } id={ id }></path>
      </svg>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you benny! You're right, the svg tag was missing.